# How can I manually create an on chain contract call?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, contract, sandbox

Using tezos sandbox mode, I am trying to test an on chain contract call in isolation of the main contract which calls it. If my contract was the Collatz template, it would like be trying to run the OnEven contract in isolation by calling it manually, rather than having the main Collatz contract execute the call.

When I try to create the on chain call however, I'm not sure how to create the storage parameter which encodes the contract (TContract) to send the data back to.

In other words, creating a contract call which has the following structure.

`parameter (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x))`

How can I find what value `contract %k` should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an address "KT1..." or "KT1...%entry_point".

The chain is then in charge of type checking and converting to the `contract` type.

Comment: Okay thanks! I tried that but I'm still having an issue with the storage. It might be a different problem though so I'll post it as a separate question.